# Attach Mouse Events to Rect WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have the following program that creates Rectangle using Rect object. I want to attach Mouse events to newly created Rect. How can I do that? Please help. Here's the code below.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="TestDrawing.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestDrawing"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid Margin="12">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Canvas>
        <Button x:Name="BtnAddRectangle" Content="Add Rectngle" Click="BtnAddRectangle_Click" Height="20"/>
            
        </Canvas>
    </StackPanel>

      <Canvas Name="canvas">
       
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TestDrawing
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        bool drag = false;
        Point startPoint;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        // this creates and adds rectangles dynamically
        

        private void BtnAddRectangle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();

            // Retrieve the DrawingContext in order to create new drawing content.
            DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();

            // Create a rectangle and draw it in the DrawingContext.
            Rect rect = new Rect(new Size(150, 100));
            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.LightBlue, null,rect);

            drawingContext.Close();
           
            canvas.Children.Add(new VisualHost { Visual = drawingVisual });
            foreach (UIElement child in canvas.Children)
            {
                //Not working
                child.MouseDown += rectangle_MouseDown;
                child.MouseMove += rectangle_MouseMove;
            }
        }
        private void rectangle_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // start dragging
            drag = true;
            // save start point of dragging
            startPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(canvas);
        }

        private void rectangle_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // if dragging, then adjust rectangle position based on mouse movement
            if (drag)
            {
                Rectangle draggedRectangle = sender as Rectangle;
                Point newPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(canvas);
                double left = Canvas.GetLeft(draggedRectangle);
                double top = Canvas.GetTop(draggedRectangle);
                Canvas.SetLeft(draggedRectangle, left + (newPoint.X - startPoint.X));
                Canvas.SetTop(draggedRectangle, top + (newPoint.Y - startPoint.Y));

                startPoint = newPoint;
            }
        }

        private void rectangle_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // stop dragging
            drag = false;
        }
    }
    public class VisualHost : UIElement
    {
        public Visual Visual { get; set; }

        protected override int VisualChildrenCount
        {
            get { return Visual != null ? 1 : 0; }
        }

        protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
        {
            return Visual;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quote from the MSDN page on [Using DrawingVisual Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/using-drawingvisual-objects):

> The [DrawingVisual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.drawingvisual) is a lightweight drawing class that is used to render shapes, images, or text. This class is considered lightweight because it does not provide layout or **event handling**, which improves its performance. For this reason, drawings are ideal for backgrounds and clip art.

If you need event handling, why not just use the existing [`Rectangle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shapes.rectangle) class? Your existing code can be easily changed to use this class instead of your custom `VisualHost`.

```
private void BtnAddRectangle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle() { Fill = Brushes.LightBlue, Width = 150, Height = 100 };
    canvas.Children.Add(rect);

    foreach (UIElement child in canvas.Children)
    {
        child.MouseDown += rectangle_MouseDown;
        child.MouseMove += rectangle_MouseMove;
    }
}
```